# JMesa: pre-sorting a table

Tags: java, jmesa

I am creating a multiple column JMesa table. I want to pre-sort the table on a specified column. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You have to call addSort() on SortSet, then associate the SortSet with the TableModel.  Sample code:

```
SortSet mySortSet = new SortSet() {};
mySortSet.addSort("your column property here", Order.ASC);
Limit limit = TableModelUtils.getLimit("table model id here", request, itemsList);
limit.setSortSet(mySortSet);
model.setLimit(limit);
```